# Error in ddply {plyr}: Error in vector(type, length) : vector: cannot make a vector of mode 'NULL'. Is it a bug?

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to calculate the change from baseline of my simulated data over time, per ID and per simulation with `ddply`:
My code:

```
tm2<- ddply(tm1, .(NSIM,ID), function(df1){
  base<-df1$DV[1]
  df1$CB<-round(df1$DV/base*100,2)
  df1})
```

It worked well till last week, and now I rerun the same code it keeps giving me error

```
"Error in vector(type, length) : 
  vector: cannot make a vector of mode 'NULL'."
```

I'm wondering if this is due to something went wrong with the plyr package, does anyone else have the same issue? Anyone can help?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What's different now than last week? Did you update R? Rstudio? Any packages?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
tm1 %>%
   group_by(NSIM, ID) %>%
   mutate(CB = round(DV/base * 100, 2))
```